# GeoServer, OpenLayers3 getGetFeatureInfo cross-site (different approach)

Tags: javascript, apache, iis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I think we are all familiar with the cross-site problem, but just in case:
I am using OpenLayers3, GeoServer on port 8080 and Apache on port 80. I render some features on map, and on click I would like to get feature info from WMS. I found the code in OpenLayers3 examples:

```
var viewResolution = v.getResolution();
var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
{'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'});
if (url) 
  $.get(url, null, function(data)
  {
  });
```

Of course I get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/geoserver/Re... . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I was searching the net and found different approaches how to handle this matter. I am asking witch way should I choose. The known facts are: hosting server will be owned, linux or windows unknown (for now). This also means that I don't know if apache or IIS will be used so lets stay opened.

The options I found are:

- CORS
- JSONP
- proxy on apache
- URL rewriting IIS 7

What should I choose if hosting web site on apache or IIS? I am not looking the easy way, I am looking for the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
I think you have two main options:

1. Using JSONP OutputFormat for GetFeatureInfo
2. Using a proxy (with some protection)

I believe 1 as a solution is clean and actually preferrable IMHO if you are developing a specific application and you know that you always be hitting GeoServer or something that supports JSONP. It avoids having to fiddle with proxies and eventual admins.

In the general case 2 is more flexible, although I would recommend to somehow limit what people can do with such a proxy to avoid having a black-hole in your infrastructure.
In our webgis [MapStore](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/mapstore) (based on OL) we use this very lean [http-proxy](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/http-proxy) we developed that can be configured to let pass only certain requests (e.g. getfeatureinfo) and only to certain servers if needed.

My 0.02€.

Comment: I am not an Apache guru, but if I understand you correctly:

ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
this two lines exposes some risks?